# Multiple colors in Python

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I am plotting a dataframe with 100+ columns and I stacked all of them for each index value, the plot is below:
[image]

However I wanted the color to be in a shading way, or at least the person can see the trend (from col1 to col100) so that it is clearer and I dont need those super long legends.

Looking forward to any advice!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "shading". Can you clarify, please?

Comment: @anon  for example, the color for first column is very light blue, and the second darker blue, the third even darker,..., the last may already black..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid specifying colours by name and instead specify RGB (or RGBA) values. For instance:

```
plot(linspace(0,4,10), linspace(0,10,10), lw=10, c=(1.0,1.0,0.90))
plot(linspace(0,5,10), linspace(0,9,10), lw=10, c=(1.0,1.0,0.80))
plot(linspace(0,6,10), linspace(0,8,10), lw=10, c=(1.0,1.0,0.70))
plot(linspace(0,7,10), linspace(0,7,10), lw=10, c=(1.0,1.0,0.60))
plot(linspace(0,8,10), linspace(0,6,10), lw=10, c=(1.0,1.0,0.50))
plot(linspace(0,9,10), linspace(0,5,10), lw=10, c=(1.0,1.0,0.40))
plot(linspace(0,10,10), linspace(0,4,10), lw=10, c=(1.0,1.0,0.30))
```

Will plot:

[image: Shades of yellow]

Here the colours are specified as an RGB 3-tuple (e.g. `c=(1.0,1.0,0.30)`) where the values range between 0 and 1 for red, green and blue components. By updating the values with various gradients you can drift between colours or shades.